# html5 video tag can't play mp4 video on android

Tags: android, html, apache, video

I am working on a simplet website project, in which I am using html5 video tag to show mp4 video. But I tested on my office apache server with very simple html5 video tag code

```
<video controls preload="metadata" style="display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;">
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>        
</video>
```

The video can't be loaded on any android devices, but it works on iOS and desktop.

Then I tried to put those code on another apache server, it works on all devices.

I checked the MIME type and mp4 file type exists on both servers. So how can I fix my office server and make the mp4 video can be shown.

Comment: Is an obligation to show only MP4 video in your HTML video tag? If it's not the case, your could add some fallback video sources in other formats like OGG and WEBM.

Answer (score 0):

Html5 video tag is only working for android lollipop os and above. Use an native VideoView to display mp4 videos. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have using the latest android already, and tested on Chrome and the stock browser, Samsung and Sony.... but none of them can see the video.